# How to identify eth token type from transaction detail using json rpc

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, rpc, web3js

I am trying to filter eth transactions according to their token type such as usdt, usdc ... by using json rpc.

i sent request like this.

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["0xab0fab9f83284c05681727241e04afdee898472c99db6ce394544badde08961a"],"id":1}
```

And this is what i received.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": {
        "blockHash": "0x5eb018487dfbc9fd2032546c39a88d816c5bc4a317796466225654713dd1780d",
        "blockNumber": "0x1232560",
        "from": "0xb91efe41e38d2d6441c45bbf7a5704b9a1beb905",
        "gas": "0x12e6a",
        "gasPrice": "0x38391146f",
        "maxFeePerGas": "0x51b4d56c3",
        "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0x5f5e100",
        "hash": "0xab0fab9f83284c05681727241e04afdee898472c99db6ce394544badde08961a",
        "input": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000775a9a35bdb24cf5f24fd10a8b720a81f8ac6c2f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007e0c657fb079d6c3fb",
        "nonce": "0x284f",
        "to": "0xedb171c18ce90b633db442f2a6f72874093b49ef",
        "transactionIndex": "0x92",
        "value": "0x0",
        "type": "0x2",
        "accessList": [],
        "chainId": "0x1",
        "v": "0x0",
        "r": "0x47074b96f77c0d7139b9e322e6fdf8284147fc146bc2fe41b837758ffc17a3b5",
        "s": "0x47702b5237eb7530aed2f99e341d74ce39422204f5a6debbff92550b47b15e10",
        "yParity": "0x0"
    }
}
```

Am wondering how I can determine this transaction's token type.

Thanks -

Comment: Do you have an etherium node url?

Answer (score 1):

This specific transaction's `to` field reflects the [WAMPL](https://etherscan.io/address/0xedb171c18ce90b633db442f2a6f72874093b49ef) token contract address, and the first 4 bytes of the `input` field (sometimes also referred to as `data` field) show that it's executing a `transfer(address,uint256)` function on the `to` contract.

For simple token transfers, the `to` field of the transaction shows the token contract address.

---

But it's also possible to send a transaction that doesn't transfer tokens directly - but as part of an internal transaction. And it's also possible to send multiple internal transactions within that one main transaction.

A great example is a DEX swap. Within one (main) transaction: Token A is transferred from your address to the DEX, and at the same time token B is transferred from the DEX to your address.

Each ERC-20 token transfer emits an event that is readable in the transaction receipt.

*Note: Transaction receipt is only available after the transaction was included in a block.*

Request:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionReceipt","params":["0xab0fab9f83284c05681727241e04afdee898472c99db6ce394544badde08961a"],"id":1}
```

Response:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": {
        "blockHash": "0x5eb018487dfbc9fd2032546c39a88d816c5bc4a317796466225654713dd1780d",
        "blockNumber": "0x1232560",
        "contractAddress": null,
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "0x9dac0a",
        "effectiveGasPrice": "0x38391146f",
        "from": "0xb91efe41e38d2d6441c45bbf7a5704b9a1beb905",
        "gasUsed": "0xb6dc",
        "logs": [
            {
                "address": "0xedb171c18ce90b633db442f2a6f72874093b49ef",
                "blockHash": "0x5eb018487dfbc9fd2032546c39a88d816c5bc4a317796466225654713dd1780d",
                "blockNumber": "0x1232560",
                "data": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007e0c657fb079d6c3fb",
                "logIndex": "0xcc",
                "removed": false,
                "topics": [
                    "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
                    "0x000000000000000000000000b91efe41e38d2d6441c45bbf7a5704b9a1beb905",
                    "0x000000000000000000000000775a9a35bdb24cf5f24fd10a8b720a81f8ac6c2f"
                ],
                "transactionHash": "0xab0fab9f83284c05681727241e04afdee898472c99db6ce394544badde08961a",
                "transactionIndex": "0x92"
            }
        ],
        "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000100000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000018000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "status": "0x1",
        "to": "0xedb171c18ce90b633db442f2a6f72874093b49ef",
        "transactionHash": "0xab0fab9f83284c05681727241e04afdee898472c99db6ce394544badde08961a",
        "transactionIndex": "0x92",
        "type": "0x2"
    }
}
```

Here you can see the event `logs`. In this case, the `topics[0]` reflects the keccak256 hash of the string `Transfer(address,address,uint256)` which is the signature of event. And the `address` of the event log shows which contract emitted the event. That's the token contract.

Keep in mind that contracts can emit all kinds of event logs. So in case of token transfers, you're only interested in these where the `topics[0]` match the specific value.

And you might run into some false positives. For example: ERC-20 and ERC-721 tokens emit the log with the same signature - but ERC-20 has 3 topics, and ERC-721 has 4 topics.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I used web3.py to analyze eth token tx for getting tx details like symbol, from, to and amount.
Hope to connect with you :)